# Custom drop down styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While working on select box, I come to know we can't write our custom styling. Then while working on it I tried few plugins but didn't achieve what I am looking for.

I am looking for a drop down having some options in black and some option in gray. Like this template but using .

[image]

Is there any jquery plugin which match my requirements or any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So find a plugin and apply different CSS to it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

It's really easy and has plenty of options.
Super-simple use like: `$(".chosen-select").chosen();`

For disabled elements check its use [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#selected-and-disabled-support)

**Edit:**
For changing the color (without disabling the options) you can do it with pure css.
Check fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eEmYZ/

(You can use it even without any plugin...)

Comment: The gray text is not disabled. Its just a color. User can click on it and he can perform some tasks.

Comment: You could change it through pure css. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/eEmYZ/

Comment: Correct, but the problem is how to add data-placeholder. I tried using it but not reflecting.Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/eEmYZ/1/

Comment: How I can achieve this without using any plugin. It would be really nice you suggest me how to achieve this.

Comment: @saorabh To use a placeholder text you need to have an empty option in your select. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/CrMaQ/2/
Without the use of a plugin, you can just change the color of the options, but you do not have many choices of further styling to make it look nice

Comment: Is there any other plugin to implement this. It not matches my requirement. Because Using a placeholder size shows only onces. On any changes it goes away.

Comment: please check this demo. http://jsfiddle.net/eEmYZ/3/ I was trying to read data attributes but no luck any help?

Comment: Check this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/ah8hq/1/.
In your fiddle, in change callback, `this` refers to the `select` element, not the `option`